# Is any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ open?

Tags: metric-spaces

My question is to consider $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, with the subspace metric. What are the open subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$? The answer to this is that any subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is open. I am struggling to prove this. Can anyone help me out? I want to prove this using the metric space characterization of open sets:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $U \subseteq X$ is an open set if for each $x \in U$ there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq U$. Where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball with radius $r$ and centre $x$.

Comment: How is one expected to prove a topology statement without any topology?

Comment: How do you define an open set if not via topology?  How do you define the subspace metric?  Write down the definitions, then see what you can do with them.

Comment: Sorry! I'm currently doing a metric spaces and basic topology course and we haven't quite gotten to the topology section yet. Everything i found online to help was using the word topology. I didn't realise that was a topological statement.

Comment: Let (X,d) be a metric space. A subset U ⊂ X is an open set if for each x ∈ U there exists r > 0 such that B(x,r) ⊂ U. Where B(x,r) is the open ball with radius r and centre x.

Comment: @pullofthemoon I've edited your question to remove the "without any topology" line.  Is this what you meant to ask?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Since every set can be written as a union of singletons, you should try to prove that singletons are open sets.

**Hint 2**:

For a singleton $\{n\}\subseteq\mathbb Z$, try to find an open set $O$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $O\cap\mathbb Z=\{n\}$

**Hint 3**:

Think of simple candidates for $O$.

Comment: Is the union of open sets open? And so if you prove each {$n$} where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is open then that implies every subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is open?

Comment: "Is the union of open sets open?"... you should already know the answer to this question if you are solving the problem you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remember that the open ball $B(x, r)$ of radius $r$ about $x$ depends on the subspace: for example, in the subspace $\Bbb{Z}$ of the metric space $\Bbb{R}$, $B(0, 2)$ means something different from what it means in $\Bbb{R}$: in $\Bbb{Z}$ it means all the integers at distance less than $2$ from $0$, not all the real numbers with that property. So in $\Bbb{Z}$, $B(0, 2)$ has just three elements. Now can you think of a $d > 0$ such that $B(i, d)$ (in $\Bbb{Z}$) is contained in any subset that contains the integer $i$?

Comment: Okay, so say we have the open ball $B(n,1/2)$ such that $n$ is any integer. Then we have the open ball $B(n,1/2}={n}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Since open balls are open we know that {$n$} is therefore open. Any subset of $Z$ will be a union of singletons {$n$} and since every union of open sets is open then every subset of $\mathbb{Z} is open.

Comment: If you have now learnt that unions of open sets are open, then, yes. My answer was intended to give you a proof that does not require that knowledge.